# Bessel decomposition from Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, bessel-functions

I am looking to decompose a signal in terms of Bessel functions. I'm aware of Hankel transforms; however, for computational reasons, I have to use Fourier transforms. Essentially, my question is: after I perform the Fourier transform of the signal, how do I "translate" that into a Bessel expansion?

I also read that the Hankel transform of zeroth order is trivially related to a 2D FT. However, I understand that this is valid only for azimuthally symmetric functions, and my signal is not.

Comment: I guess I could just take overlap integrals between the Bessel polynomials and the Fourier transform...? Just thought about this, might be bs.

Comment: Essentially you are splitting the Fourier transform integrals along the radial/spherical coordinates.

Comment: Since the Fourier transform outputs weights of cosines and sines of particular frequencies, maybe you can use the identities $J_{-\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi x}}\cos(x)$ and $J_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi x}}\sin(x)$ to express the signal in terms of Bessel functions.